# Show a pgu Radio Button selected by default

Tags: python, user-interface, pgu

I'm using pgu to create radio buttons and I would like have one selected by default. That's my code:

```
from pgu import text, gui as pgui 
lo = pgui.Container(width=200)
rbt = pgui.Table()
radio = pgui.Group()        

rb1 = pgui.Radio(radio, "OP_1")
rb2 = pgui.Radio(radio, "OP_2")

rb1l = pgui.Label("OP_1_Label")
rb2l = pgui.Label("OP_2_Label")

lo.add(rbt,200,50)
radio.connect(pgui.CHANGE, My_Function_Action_Radio, (My_parameters))
```

It works perfectly, but I would like to show rb1 selected on the first time the program is executed.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You would use radio.value = "OP_1". Here is a modified snipped of gui5.py from the example in the PGU downloads which makes the first radio button selected by default.

```
g = gui.Group()
c.td(gui.Radio(g,value=1))
c.td(gui.Radio(g,value=2))
c.td(gui.Radio(g,value=3))
g.value=1
```